# Post url 404 not found

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am using angular.js and Spring MVC.
My UI code is

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

 < div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 < input type="text" ng-model="firstname">

 < input type="text" ng-model="lastname">

 < input type="text" ng-model="username">

 < input type="text" ng-model="password">

 < button ng-click="myFunction()"></button>

  < /div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {    
$scope.myFunction = function() {

   var fname=$scope.firstname;
   var lname=$scope.lastname;
   alert("firstname "+fname+"lastname "+lname);
   var sd={"fn":fname,"ln":lname};
   $http.post('newreg', {"firsname" : "ram"}).success(function(data){
        alert("Success");
    });
   };
  });
</script>
< /body>
 < /html>
```

My Spring controller code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newreg",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String urlviewer(@RequestParam(value = "firsname") String firstname,Model model){
    System.out.println("first name "+firstname);
    return "newpage";

}
```

It is working for other metthods which do not have get or post requests.
 I have included the following jars:

```
    commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

    jackson-core-asl-1.6.3.jar

    jackson-jaxrs-1.6.3.jar

    jackson-mapper-asl-1.6.3.jar

    jstl-1.2.jar

    junit-4.11.jar

    spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

    spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

    spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

    spring-context-support-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

    spring-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

    spring-expression-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

    spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

    spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

    spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

    spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

    spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
```

Do I have to include further jars?

Comment: In **$http.post()** pass full url of api. example **http://localhost:8080/newreg**.

Comment: no i am using spring mvc its just url newreg

Comment: Depends what 404 means for you - missing resource or angular cannot find it (or even both)

Comment: I am getting error as POST http://localhost:8082/SpringMVCBasic/newreg 404 not found. It is happening for only get and post requests i have tried for just urls it is working fine.

Comment: showing error at angular.js:10765 in browser console